# Происхождение выражения «Испанский стыд»

Tags: этимология

Это выражение означает стыд за кого-либо. Почему именно испанский?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Наиболее вероятным мне кажется происхождение от английского "Spanish shame" («испанский стыд»), которое в английском произошло от испанского ["vergüenza ajena"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verg%C3%BCenza_ajena) (можно перевести как «стыд за другого»).

То есть сначала в английском появился испанский термин. Он упоминается в [Википедии](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix_talk:Terms_considered_difficult_or_impossible_to_translate_into_English#Spanish) в разделе «Термины, трудные или невозможные для перевода».
А потом вместо оригинального выражения на испанском стали использовать "Spanish shame".
Сейчас, насколько я поняла, в английском могут использоваться оба варианта.

Как и когда это выражение попало в русский язык?
Поиск в [Национальном корпусе русского языка](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%C8%F1%EF%E0%ED%F1%EA%E8%E9%20%F1%F2%FB%E4) ничего не находит.
Поиск в Гугле целого выражения "испанский стыд" с ограничением до 2000 года не показывает ссылок (именно на целое выражение), а с ограничением [до 2010 года](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=active&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2010&q=%22%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B4%22&oq=%22%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B4%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i19l4j0i22i30i19l2.4145.6401.0.7629.2.2.0.0.0.0.140.275.0j2.2.0.ecynfh...0...1.1.64.serp..0.2.274.Jd4cTLjwOGw) показывает всего 7 ссылок. То есть в этот период оно начало использоваться.

Зачем оно нужно в русском языке, если уже есть выражение «стыд за другого»?
Вопрос остается открытым.

Comment: В Английском не употребляется "spanish shame", вместо этого используется "vicarious shame". Spanish shame никто не поймет, если вы употребите его в разговоре. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298548/word-for-vicarious-shame-spanish-verg%C3%BCenza-ajena